# Can I overwrite a CKEditor5 widget with another one, keeping the functionality of both?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor5

Sorry if the title of the question was confusing.

I am rewriting a widget I had in CKEditor4, and converting it to work with CKEditor5.

My problem is that I need the entire widget layout to be made with a table. So I created my widget and wrote all the converters.

When I disable the table plugin in CKEditor5, my widget works perfectly.
But if the table plugin is loaded, my widget is not inserted, instead the table plugin takes over and inserts a normal table.

So my question is: **Can I disable the table plugin only when inserting my widget, while keeping table functionality for normal tables inserted in the editor?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anwsering my own question in case anyone happens to have this problem too:

The converter has the [ConverterPriority](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_conversion_conversion-ConverterDefinition.html#) parameter.

Passing the converterPriority as 'highest' in my widget converters solved the issue, keeping the functionality of both the table and my plugin.